# Best way to reset pending intent in background after reboot in Android 2021

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I'm building a reminder app. And when reboot the device, the alarms already have been set as `pending intent` in alarm manager is destroyed. So when reboot:

1. Wake broadcastReceiver
2. BroadcastReciever calls an Activity
3. This Activity sets pending Intent again.

It worked well. However, I used an Activity, so this Activity shows up on the display a second after reboot. That's not really good. So I want to make this work on background.

Then, I noticed I can use `IntentService`.
However, `IntentService` is deprecated in API level 30.
Also `JobIntentSerive` is deprecated too.

I'm very confused. What should I use to make this work on background?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the alarms directly in the `BroadcastReceiver` called at boot time. You don't need to launch any other components to do this.

Comment: It worked. I'm just curious, is it no problem to having long-running operations in BroadcastReceiver such as querying data base? I did it and it worked though. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: You shouldn't have long-running operations in a `BroadcastReceiver` because the receiver is only given a certain amount of time to run. However, this can vary from device to device. If you need to contact a server or something like that, you would need to launch a `Service` to do that.